# ActivityContext not able to provide through Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Requirement: HomeManager which is a normal Kotlin class, it's object and data should be there until HomeActivity is getting destroyed. If I inject HomeManager to TestActivity, then I should get a new object (which is working fine also).

What is the problem with this code?

Error: cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Code:

```
/**
 * This class is used to provide object implementation which is Activity scoped.
 */
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
@Module
object InternalObjectModule {
    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideHomeManager(@ActivityContext context: Context) =
        HomeManager(context)
}
```

If I use this, it is working fine:

```
(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
```

EDIT:
HomeManager:

```
class HomeManager (private val context: Context) {
    private var shop: ShopData? = null

    fun setShop(mShop: ShopData) {
        shop = mShop
    }

    fun getShop(): ShopData? {
        return shop

    }

    fun getContext(): Context {
        return context
    }
}
```

Please note: HomeManager is a normal class and it will be used for HomeActivity related functionality

Comment: Maybe try `ActivityComponent` in `@InstallIn` if you need the `HomeManager` to be Activity scoped. Also see: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#generated-components

Comment: Hi @Darshan If I do installin with ActivityComponent, dagger is giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` is intentionally not provided in the `ActivityRetainedComponent`, as it can otherwise lead to memory leaks (by definition your object outlives the  `Activity` scope).

If you simply need a `Context` you can still inject an `@ApplicationContext`. Or as mentioned by Darshan, switch to `ActivityComponent` if your object should be recreated along with the `Activity`.

The [Component default bindings](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-default) section of the docs shows what is provided by each component.

Comment: Hi Kevin, installin with ActivityComponent, dagger is giving same error. Also point to be noted: If I use @ ApplicationContext then what is the meaning to scope for activity. My homemanager and it's data should be destroyed with activity, it's ok if it survive configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample project to check out this issue, and I did manage to encounter the error you've provided.

The problem is, as I said earlier in comments that you are not using the right component.
Try the below approach which should work (tested):

**InternalObjectModule:**

```kotlin
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class) // << Activity scoped
@Module
object InternalObjectModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideHomeManager(@ActivityContext context: Context) = HomeManager(context)
}
```

**HomeManager:**

```kotlin
class HomeManager(private val context: Context) {

    private var shop: ShopData? = null

    fun setShop(mShop: ShopData) = apply { shop = mShop }

    fun getShop(): ShopData? = shop

    fun getContext(): Context = context
}

// Some custom data object / class.
object ShopData
```

**MainActivity:**

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() /* or ComponentActivity */ {

    @Inject
    lateinit var homeManager: HomeManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("StackPlayground", homeManager.getContext().javaClass.simpleName)
    }
}
```

---

The logcat prints:

1. `D/StackPlayground: MainActivity` if I use `@ActivityContext`
2. `D/StackPlayground: HiltApplication` if I use `@ApplicationContext`
   (Note: `HiltApplication` is a class extending `Application` class with `@HiltAndroidApp`)